# How to get the month depending on the week number in C# and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, date

How can I get the *month* according to a specified *week number*? For example, if a get the week number `2` return the month `1` (`January`)?

Comment: You can't do that, unless you have year and day of week... Week can easily span multiple months, and it's kind of different each year.

Comment: What if the week spans multiple months?  What day of the week do you want to use?  Are you assuming the current year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the week number and multiply it by 7. For example, if it is week number 12, multiply 12 by 7. This will indicate the number of days it has been, rounded to the nearest week.

Divide this number by 30. In the example, the number we derived from the calculation was 84. 84 divided by 30 is 2.8

Use this number to figure out the month. 2.8 means that it is March. The number before the decimal point indicates the months past. Always round the number up, this will give you the current month.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_7444970_calculate-month-week-number.html#ixzz2zYJVK4S8

Comment: That doesn't work for every date. Take week 13, of which the Monday is on 2014-03-31 (assuming the first Monday of the year starts week 1). This gives us 13 x 7 = 91. 91 / 30 = 3.033.. That works out as March has just passed and we're now in April. It also fails again on week 26 which starts on 2014-06-30, week 30 that starts on 2014-07-28, etc. Using any day as the "month" reference trips over this at some point in the year, progressively more frequently towards the end of the year due to the usage of 30 day months. Using 31 trips week 22 with 2014-06-01. 30.5 manages to make it through 2014.

Comment: If you use 30.5 and go back to 2013, it then fails on week 13, 2013-04-01.

Comment: I agree with you, this calculation is an approximate calculation, because some weeks share the month. If you can find a better approach you can share it here. In the question itself, year is not specified that's why I put this in here.

Comment: As per the other comments, the question is flawed. Any answer based on that will be equally flawed.  Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first we should come to terms; since week can start in one month and ends in second month, let's find out in which month the given week **starts** and **ends** in separate methods.

Let's implement `WeekStart`: given a `date` we want to find out the corresponding week start date:

```
private static DateTime WeekStart(DateTime date, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek) {
  DayOfWeek current = date.DayOfWeek;

  return (current >= firstDayOfWeek)
    ? date.Date.AddDays(firstDayOfWeek - current)
    : date.Date.AddDays(-7 + (int)firstDayOfWeek - (int)current);
}
```

Then we can try to *guess* the right week; then we have to *correct* it (take previous or next week when required):

```
private static DateTime NthWeekStart(
  int year, int week, CalendarWeekRule rule, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek) {
  
  DateTime guess = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays((week - 1) * 7);

  // Or CurrentCulture 
  int actual = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
    guess, rule, firstDayOfWeek);

  return WeekStart(guess.AddDays((week - actual) * 7), firstDayOfWeek);
}
```

Finally, we can get corresponding months:

```
private static int WeekStartMonth(
  int year, int week, CalendarWeekRule rule, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek) {

  return NthWeekStart(year, week, rule, firstDayOfWeek).Month; 
}

private static int WeekEndMonth(
  int year, int week, CalendarWeekRule rule, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek) {

  return NthWeekStart(year, week, rule, firstDayOfWeek).AddDays(6).Month;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
int year              = 2020;
int week              = 36;
CalendarWeekRule rule = CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay;
DayOfWeek day         = DayOfWeek.Sunday;

int monthStart = WeekStartMonth(year, week, rule, day);
int monthEnd   = WeekEndMonth(year, week, rule, day); 

Console.Write($"{week}th week of {year} starts in month #{monthStart} ends in month #{monthEnd}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
36th week of 2020 starts in month #8 ends in month #9
```